# Hide bootstrap's .dropdown-backdrop, CSS only

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to hide Bootstrap's .dropdown-backdrop element for a certain dropdown (not all on the page) by using CSS only?

I've determined that this is possible using Javascript, with [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a55unr3t/2/). However, I would like to accomplish this without using additional JS if possible.

```
<!-- First dropdown: no backdrop -->
<div id="firstDropdown" class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn-dropdown-add btn btn-blue" data-toggle="dropdown">
        First Dropdown &#x25BC;
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a class="a_dropdown_item" href="#business">Business</a></li>
        <li><a class="a_dropdown_item" href="#my-events">Event</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Second dropdown: yes backdrop -->
<div id="secondDropdown" class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn-dropdown-add btn btn-blue" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Second Dropdown &#x25BC;
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a class="a_dropdown_item" href="#business">Business</a></li>
        <li><a class="a_dropdown_item" href="#my-events">Event</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Hide backdrop from #firstDropdown.
    // This can be done with JS as below. Can it be done with only CSS?
    $('#firstDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
      $(".dropdown-backdrop").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain why the requirement for only CSS?

Comment: Not unless it's a decendant or sibling of the menu in question.

Comment: @isherwood, good point. Turns out that the .dropdown-backdrop element is a descendant of its dropdown menu. That will likely lead me to a working solution.

Comment: @VincentFaller, I'm hoping to use only CSS mostly out of curiosity, also because I feel it's a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found solution: .dropdown-backdrop is a descendant of its .dropdown, which can have a unique ID, so simply using `display:none;` in CSS works fine, as in:

```
#firstDropdown .dropdown-backdrop {
    display:none;
}
```

And then all other dropdowns (except #firstDropdown) will still have a backdrop as normal.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a55unr3t/4/) updated.

Comment: Should I be seeing a backdrop in your fiddle? I don't in Chrome.

Comment: The backdrop appears on mobile devices only, according to the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/), so try on modal or chrome emulator

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it was screen size-based.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. I just spend 14 hours debugging an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612895/links-and-ng-clicks-in-bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-on-chrome-48-for-windows-8) on Chrome for Windows 8 where I couldn't click links in a dropdown. Turns out that hiding the backdrop solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you :) glad that my solution was of help to you, @ACIDSTEALTH -- happy coding!

Comment: I had a problem with backdrop on a windows laptop on Chrome, turns out it was because the class shows up for touch-screen laptops too.

Comment: Is there any chance this is related to a bootstrap update?  Ours as working forever, and just stopped recently.  Regardless, thanks for the help!